# Please help me understand what the tipping point of this Pedestal Table will be?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, moment-of-inertia, statics, weight

I am brand new here. I am a furniture maker and designing an Oval Pedestal Table for a client. I presented a design that I felt comfortable with, however my client has asked that I shrink the footprint of the base to a size that makes me feel uncomfortable. I have searched the web high and low and found equations, but my brain cannot wrap around them. I can build virtually anything, but my mathematical physics is not nearly as strong as my building abilities. Can any of you assist me with understanding what the tipping point of this piece will be? Specifically the skinny side? I want to be sure that if a 150lb - 175lb person uses the table to help them stand up, that the table is not going to tip over.

The Wooden Table Base will weigh approx 140lbs
The Glass Table Top will weigh approx 175lbs
Total Weight = approx 315lbs

I am attaching images of the side and front elevations with dimensions. I have made a number of versions of this table and have included an oval coffee table size for reference as well.
Any and all help will be most appreciated. Thank you all in advance.
[image: Elevations of Table Design]
[image: Example of Coffee Table]

Comment: What exactly is meant by "tipping point"? Do you mean what is the angle required for it to tip over? Probably somehow lowering the center of mass can help with that, in case that is what you mean...

Comment: If you are concerned with tipping but don’t want to alter the appearance of the table, the simplest thing to do is add weight to the base. That lowers the center of gravity of the table making harder to tip over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the tipping point of complex objects (or combination of objects)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/767850/146039).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine tipping point for a single pedestal dining table?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/354588/how-to-determine-tipping-point-for-a-single-pedestal-dining-table)

Comment: I know the top part says it's closed for engineering, but I think that the duplicate I've proposed answers the question.